# How to list servers running in Ubuntu machine along with their port numbers?

Tags: networking, server, nmap

Among some other servers installed in my Ubuntu system, one is the `dictd` server. The documentation says it uses port `2628`. Running

```
sudo nmap 192.168.1.74 -p 0-9000
```

results in:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.74
Host is up (0.000010s latency).
Not shown: 8995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
3128/tcp open  squid-http
```

It does not list port `2628` used by `dictd` server (which is up, I checked with `ps`.) I don't know what's wrong with the command that I used!

*My question is how can I list all servers (like `dictd` and others including some games serves) along with their port numbers?* (preferably using console tools)

Comment: Only I can say is to try with netcat. command:  netcat -z -n -v -w 1 192.168.1.74 1-9000 2>&1 | grep succeeded. Netcat will try to make connection and if service run you will see

Comment: @2707974 that gives the same ports as listed above with `nmap`..

Comment: dictd work on tcp port by default, I think. Try to scan udp ports nc -vvzu 192.168.1.74 1-9000 -w 1

Comment: no positives with udp ports either..

Comment: If service work and use tcp must be in LISTEN state because waiting for connection. netstat -l, must see it.

Answer (score 1):

This task is what the [`netstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/netstat.8.html) tool is for. Nmap is a great port scanner, but the kernel is more authoritative, since firewalls can block a port scan.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of processes running:

```sh
netstat -nltp
```

Output:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37261         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46624         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      44178/kited         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

See `netcat --help` for each one of the flags used.